# How Can I Reference A Font File In CSS For My Visualforce Page through Static Resources?

Tags: visualforce, css, static-resources, css3

I have a .css file that I have zipped along with image assets and font assets.

On the front end through my Visualforce page I am bringing this css file in as an <apex: stylesheet>

Here's what I have:

`@font-face { font-family: Some-font; src: url("fonts/some-font.woff2"); font-weight: 300; }`

My question is how can I refer to the src? I know on the front end we can use {!URLFOR($Resource...

however that does not seem to work in CSS.

Importing fonts as a `<style>` tag on the front end page is not an option either since I want it to apply to other pages also.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Wouldn't it help to create a VF component which imports all fonts or specific fonts and use it in all VF pages?

Comment: Good point, but I don't have access to all pages.  Some of them are out of the box for B2B Commerce.  I'd have to create overrides for every page.  I would think there has to be a more efficient way.

Comment: Ok looks like the only way to do it is through a component.  But pulled it in through the header component so it applies to all pages for now.